# Do I have to file Form 8843 even if I fail the substantial presence test?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, non-resident

Given the following presence in the U.S.:

- (All previous years are only short tourist trips)
- 2016: 6 days (all under VWP)
- 2017: 0 days
- 2018: 87 days (4 VWP + 83 J-1)

The presence under the J-1 visa is for paid work at a university (after which I will return to Europe and do not plan to immediately travel to the U.S. except maybe short tourist trips in the near future).

When filing the 1040NR(-EZ) tax return, will I have to file Form 8843 in order to exclude days from counting with respect to the substantial presence test as an exempt individual?

To my understanding, I would fail the substantial presence test for 2018 anyway, even if I did count the J-1 days, which means I could "save" the exemption (which I am allowed to claim only twice) for later years in case I happen to work under a J-1 visa in the U.S. again.

The statement on the IRS website is not clear to me and sounds like filing Form 8843 is not ultimately necessary:

> If you exclude days of presence in the U.S. for purposes of the substantial presence test because you were an exempt individual [...], you must include Form 8843, [...], with your income tax return.

From: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/substantial-presence-test

---

Presume following future:

- 2019: 0 days
- 2020: 92 days (J-1, starting a 2-year postdoc in Oct)
- 2021: 365 days (J-1)
- 2022: 273 days (J-1)

If I don't have to claim exemption during my first two calendar years with J-1 presence (2018 and 2020), during which I will fail the substantial presence test anyway, I could save the J-1 exemption for 2021 and 2022 and could be taxed as a non-resident alien for these two years, too. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are an "exempt individual" for your days (even if only 1 day) on J-1 status that year if the conditions apply to you. You cannot "choose" not to be an exempt individual to "save it" for later use. As a non-student J-1, you are an exempt individual (i.e. your days on J-1 are exempt from the Substantial Presence Test) as a "teacher or trainee" unless you have previously been an exempt individual for any part of 2 of the previous 6 calendar years.

The fact that you would also fail the Substantial Presence Test for 2018 if your days on J-1 were counted is irrelevant -- your days on J-1 in 2018 are not counted, because you are an exempt individual, and you have no choice in that. (The only case where you have a choice is if you are *past* the first 2 years, so that you are normally not an exempt individual, and thus your days are counted for the SPT, but you want to still be an exempt individual and have your days *not* counted for the SPT, you could do that by claiming Closer Connection to a Foreign Country. That doesn't apply to you because you are still in your first 2 years.) You are forced to be an "exempt individual" for your days on J-1 status in 2018 and 2020, and you will not be an "exempt individual" for your days on J-1 status in 2021 and 2022 (which means you will meet the SPT for those years and you will be a resident alien for those years), unless, as explained above, you claim Closer Connection to a Foreign Country.

Comment: These two sentences: 'You cannot "choose" not to be an exempt individual to "save it" for later use.' and 'You are forced to be an "exempt individual" for your days on J-1 status [...]' are the relevant points of your comment to me. This is how I would have interpreted the rules if in doubt, even though I still claim that what I have quoted from irs.gov is ambiguous regarding that matter and it could be interpreted a different way.
What is your source of the interpretation of the rules, @user102008?